# Satisfy protocol requirement with property of covariant type

Tags: swift

I have a protocol which has a property requirement:

```
protocol V {}

protocol P {
  var v: V? { get }
}
```

The problem is that only property of type `V` can satisfy this requirement. The following code compiles:

```
class A: P {
  var v: V?
}
```

But the following does not:

```
protocol Some: V {}

class B: P {
  var v: Some?
}

protocol Another {}

class C: P {
  var v: (Another & V)?
}
```

That is, neither covariant nor protocol composition types can satisfy protocol requirements. This seems to be quite an old (and very unfortunate) limitation of the compiler (see https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-55).

**Question:** Are there any workarounds for this limitation?

---

<sup>Another question: there are several duplicates and related issues on Swift issue tracker, but none of them seems to match this one exactly. Is there any point in posting this issue?</sup>

Comment: Should the type annotation of `v` in `C` above be `(Another & V)?` rather than `(Another & P)?`?

Comment: @dfri yes, you are right, it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Question**: Are there any workarounds for this limitation?

You could use an `associatedtype` in `P` (conforming to `V`) that is used as the type annotation of `v` in `P`, and use this `associatedtype` as a generic typeholder for types conforming to `P`.

```
protocol V {}

protocol P {
    associatedtype T: V
    var v: T? { get }
}

/* typeholder conformance via protocol inheritance */
protocol Some: V {}    

class B<T: Some>: P {
    var v: T?
}

/* ... protocol composition */
protocol Another {}    

class C<T: Another & V>: P {
    var v: T?
}
```